# WP Pagenavi / custom post type / custom page template 404 error

Tags: navigation, custom-post-type, wordpress

Can someone help me out with this damn pagenavi problem? I have been trying all the possible solutions I found on stackoverflow and other forums, but I still get a 404 error when I want to visit the second page of the pagenavi.

I stripped the code as clean as can be. This should work, right?

```
<?php 
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'professionals',
        'paged' => $paged
    ) );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();


    echo '<div>'. the_title() .'</div>';


    endwhile;

    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Some more info: I am using a custom page template, different custom post types on the website and also a blog which includes pagenavi also (that does work). I also tried resetting the permalink every time I changed the code, also not helping.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Found the solution. Hope this helps someone else too.

I installed the plugin Custom Post Type UI to easily add custom post types. I had to change a setting of this plugin to make it work. When you set Rewrite to false (for your custom post type) it will work. Don't forget to flush the permalink settings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Enter Wordpress admin 
Settings > Reading -> Chang "Blog pages show at most" to 5 
Hope It solve the problem for you.